# how to compare two date in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get list of users who subscribed before 30 days, i used $lt to compare date but i get nothing, any help please!

- this is my schema model:

```
var VisitorsSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    subDate: Date
}, {
    collection: 'users'
});
```

- this how i'm trying to get users subscribed before 30 days :

```
users.find({
    "subDate": {
        $lt: new Date(new Date().setDate(new
            Date().getDate() - 30))
    }
}, function (err, resp) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    console.log(resp);
    res.send(resp);
});
```

Note: when i get one user and compare his date of subscribe like this:

```
res.send(resp[0]['subDate']>de);
```

it works fine and i get correct result(true or false).

Comment: var de=new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-30));

Comment: subDate's format in mongo is like this : 2017-10-05T11:25:00+02:00

Comment: i try to work with moment.js library, i have added this part of cide just to get all users subscribed before to day but i get nothing :                                             
      const today = moment().startOf('day');                                             
           visitors.find({
  "creationDate": {
   $lte:today
  } 
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved by adding toISOString() :

```
$lte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-daysNumber)).toISOString()
```